# How to Count records in a table

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a drop down list in my website showing a list of available topics, however each topic is linked with a list of titles that belong to, how can I show the number of available titles associated with this topic using an sql query.

this is the structure of my tables :

**Topics Table**

```
TopicId (int) , TopicTitle (varchar 50)
```

---

**Titles Table**

```
TitleId (int), Title (varchar 50), TopicId
```

and the structure of the drop down list is for example :

Sports 10

Education 4

...

Comment: have you tried anything, do you have sample code?

Comment: How are you accessing your database?  What format are you after?

Answer (score 3):

You can use that query to get the information you need:

```
SELECT To.TopicTitle, COUNT(Ti.TitleId) as TopicCount
FROM Topics To
INNER JOIN Titles Ti ON To.TopicId = Ti.TitleId
GROUP BY To.TopicId, To.TopicTitle
```

Answer (score 2):

It is  a basic [COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) query on the Titles table in join with the Topics table

```
SELECT t.TopicTitle as Topic, Count(tt.TopicID) as TitlesForTopic
FROM Titles tt INNER JOIN Topics t
ON tt.TopicID = t.TopicID
GROUP BY tt.TopicID, t.TopicTitle
ORDER BY COUNT(tt.TopicID) DESC
```

From C# is basically

```
string cmdText = "...the above query ....";
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    cn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    gridView.DataSource = dt;
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TopicTitle, tt.Count
from Topics t inner join 
   (select count(*) as Count, TopicId 
     from Titles group by TopicId) tt
on t.TopicId = tt.TopicId
```

Comment: Szymon's will be more efficient.